# Should OverwriteList always be applied even when using a FixedLength byteArray

Tags: protobuf-net

I've read about the couple of issues with array handling of bytes in protobuf, and just wanted to make sure that I'm doing stuff correctly. If I omit the `OverwriteList` each time that I Load/Save my bytes increases in size. So is the correct approach if you are using an Array or List to always have Overwrite specified if you provide a Default Value for that Property?

```
[ProtoContract]
class Settings
{
    public Settings()
    {
        AccessCode = new byte[6];
        Message = "hello";
        Random r = new Random();
        r.NextBytes(AccessCode);
    }

    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList=true)]
    public byte[] AccessCode { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using from the Souce 2.0.0.569 of protobuf.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Settings s = new Settings();
            Display(s);

            Serializer.Serialize<Settings>(ms, s);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            Settings newSettings = Serializer.Deserialize<Settings>(ms);
            Display(newSettings);
        }
    }

    static void Display(Settings s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Access Code Length = {0} Message = {1}", s.AccessCode.Length, s.Message);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in your case I would say the most appropriate fix would be:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
class Settings
{
    public Settings()
    {
        AccessCode = new byte[6];
        Message = "hello";
        Random r = new Random();
        r.NextBytes(AccessCode);
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] AccessCode { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

but *without* specifying `OverwriteList`. This will avoid the additional redundant initialization steps.

To explain `OverwriteList`: protobuf, as designed by google, is designed to be append-able and merge-able. Because of this, for multi-value data (lists, arrays, etc), the specification behaviour is to *append* the new values on the end; `OverwriteList` allows the new values to *replace* the old ones - but another approach there is simple: don't have any old values.

As an unrelated note; `new Random()` can lead to confusing scenarios where a group of objects created in a tight loop have *identical* values. If this is likely to be a problem, consider using a `static` instance instead, for example:

```
static readonly Random rand = new Random();

public Settings()
{
    AccessCode = new byte[6];
    Message = "hello";
    lock(rand)
    {
        rand.NextBytes(AccessCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: cool thanks. This was a contrived example, but i like the tip on the Random that's cool

Comment: @Paul if your *actual* example is more complex, you can also use things like serialization-callbacks to make sure that everything is in the right state at the right time

Comment: Cheers yeah in some of my other projects I use `AfterDeserialise` etc to reattach objects to their parents.